# Can I use my phone Hotspots to access web in virtualbox

Tags: windows-7, router

Can I use my phone hotspots to access virtualbox web? 
I can't ping 8.8.8.8 Google,
I can't reach network in my virtualbox,
I can't connect my router to virtualbox,
Is that because I am using my phone hotspots or maybe wrong configuration

Comment: It's a mystery what your current setup looks like and what you're trying to achieve though it likely has something to do with internet access.

Comment: A bad configuration is the more likely culprit (whether VirtualBox or one of the OSes involved). That said, there some mobile providers do have specific requirements for PC/browsers to access their connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question.

In virtual box the mode of your networking ie **bridged** makes a difference also.  The right mode depends on exactly how your trying to share your internet.

You need to plug a wifi adapter into the physical hardware or host OS.
Then in virtual box you need to dedicate the wifi adapter a single VM.
Load the drivers inside the VM.
configure ssid and etc
You should now be able to connect to the wifi.

OR

You may want the host to have wifi, and share it with the VM's.

Setup the wifi adapter on the host
configure the SSID,encryption, and yada yada

Now either you need to pick an unused IP address on the same subnet inside your VM OR setup a DHCP server and use a different subnet.

Windows you will want to use **Intenet connection sharing** or ICS or far more complicated setup your or DHCP server.

Linux setup bind (DHCP server) and turn ON (sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip.forward=1) and to /etc/sysctl.conf (net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1)

Comment: My virtualbox Machines is win7, and I am trying to ping Windows from router2 but it is not ping able.

Answer (score 1):

Does your host machine have Internet connection via your phone’s hotspot?

If the answer is yes, then go to the settings and under network, set the connection type as bridged. Then select the WiFi as the network source in the next step. Restart the VM and it should work.

If for some reason it still doesn’t work and you are running Centos/RHEL, run this command:

```
nmcli con show
```

If your primary interface doesn’t show or it’s down, you need to bring it up by:

```
nmcli con up *interface-name*
```

Else, just create one with the command:

```
nmcli con add con-name *a name* type 802-ethernet... ifname *interface name* autoconnect yes
```

I don’t remember the type very well but hitting the tab key should autocomplete that for you.